# Where to make a toggle action in this react redux code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, es6-class

I have 2 files here:
App.js  and   reducer.js
I try to use React & Redux for creating onclick toggle action (ex: background color change).
Can anyone help me to where can I make toggle action in this code? (I made setTimeout action in mapDispatchToProps before and it worked but toggle action not.)
see the code:

```
App.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          style={{
            backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor
          }}
        >
          hello
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.props.changeTheColor}>change</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    backgroundColor: state.backgroundColor
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    changeTheColor: () => {
      dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_COLOR" }); //I think something should change here but I have no idea how :(
    }
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

and reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  backgroundColor: "red"
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const updatedState = { ...state };

  if (action.type === "CHANGE_COLOR") {
    updatedState.backgroundColor = "yellow";  // I added else/if operation there before and didn't worked :(
  }

  return updatedState;
};

export default reducer;
```

does someone has any idea(s) how to make toggle action there? 
I want to change button red background color to yellow and toggle back the acton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code like this:

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.changeTheColor(this.props.backgroundColor === 'red' ? 'yellow' : 'red')}>change</button>             

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
        changeTheColor: (value) => {
          dispatch(changeColor(value));
        }
      };
    };

    const changeColor = (value) => {
      return {
        type: 'CHANGE_COLOR',
        value
      };
    };

    const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {             
       switch (action.type) {
          case "CHANGE_COLOR" : {
             return { ...state, backgroundColor : action.value }  
          }
          default:
            return state
     };
```